# How to send email with attachment using InputStream

Tags: java, file, inputstream, mime-message

Hello first i get my pdf from my frontend

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/enviarCorreoAdjunto", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 @ResponseBody
 ResponseMetadata enviarCorreoAdjunto(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile, @RequestParam("ruta") String Ruta,
        Model model) {
            String result; 
    boolean resultado = false;
            try {
        // System.out.println("MILYmultipartFile"+ multipartFile.getInputStream());
        resultado = procesoOperacionesDao.enviarCorreoAdjunto(Ruta, multipartFile.getInputStream());     
 ResponseMetadata metadata = new ResponseMetadata();
        metadata.setMessage("success");
        metadata.setData(result);
        metadata.setStatus(200);
        return metadata;
}
```

when i tried with  messageHelper.addAttachment("attachement",new ByteArrayResource(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream))) i get an error

```
@Override
    public boolean 
    enviarCorreoAdjunto(String targetPath, InputStream inputStream) throws Exception {

            System.out.println("PROBANDO INGRESO COREO");
            final MimeMessagePreparator messagePreparator = mimeMessage -> {
            final MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);
            messageHelper.setFrom("automatizacion@gmail.com");
            messageHelper.setTo("hportillap@gmail.com");
            messageHelper.setSubject("REPORTE DE PLAN DE CUMPLIMIENTO");
            messageHelper.setText("PRUEBA", true);
            messageHelper.addAttachment("attachement",new ByteArrayResource(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream)));
            //messageHelper.addAttachment("attachement", new ByteArrayResource(inputStream.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)), MediaType.TEXT_HTML.toString());
            };
            try {
                    javaMailSender.send(messagePreparator);
            } catch (final MailException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }           
            return true;
    }
```

when i run the function without the attachment it works and i get the mail

Comment: What do you mean with it not working? Is it throwing an exception?

Comment: Yes, org.springframework.mail.MailPreparationException: Could not prepare mail; neste
d exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not in multipart mode - create a
n appropriate MimeMessageHelper via a constructor that takes a 'multipart' flag
if you need to set alternative texts or add inline elements or attachments.

Comment: Yes, Thank you thank you